# Creating new array from given array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I've array like this in php:

```
Array
(
    [Color] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pink
            [1] => Pink
            [2] => Pink
            [3] => Pink
        )

    [Size] => Array
        (
            [0] => S
            [1] => S
            [2] => S
            [3] => M
        )

    [Brand] => Array
        (
            [0] => Raymond
            [1] => Levis
            [2] => Lee
            [3] => Raymond
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1500
            [1] => 1500
            [2] => 1500
            [3] => 1600
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )
)
```

I want to create new array from the above array like this:

```
    Array(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Pink
            [Size] => S
            [Brand] => Raymond
            [price] => 1500
            [quantity] => 2
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Pink
            [Size] => S
            [Brand] => Levis
            [price] => 1500
            [quantity] => 2
        )
    )
```

and so on. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? Post your attempts

Comment: do a little bit google. you'll find it.

Comment: hint: first level `for` loop, second level `foreach` keys

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($old as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $k => $val) {
        $new[$k][$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make two loops over input array like this:

```
<?php

$input = array (
    'Color' => array (
        'Pink',
        'Pink',
        'Pink',
        'Pink'
    ),

    'Size' => array (
        'S',
        'S',
        'S',
        'M'
    ),

    'Brand' => array (
        'Raymond',
        'Levis',
        'Lee',
        'Raymond'
    ),

    'price' => array (
        1500,
        1550,
        1500,
        1600
    )
);

$output = array();

foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $k => $val) {
        $output[$k][$key] = $val;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);

/*
    OUTPUT:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Color] => Pink
                [Size] => S
                [Brand] => Raymond
                [price] => 1500
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Color] => Pink
                [Size] => S
                [Brand] => Levis
                [price] => 1550
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Color] => Pink
                [Size] => S
                [Brand] => Lee
                [price] => 1500
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Color] => Pink
                [Size] => M
                [Brand] => Raymond
                [price] => 1600
            )

    )
*/

?>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. It Solves My Problem. Thanks Very Much. I Really Appreciate it. Keep up the good work.